# Better approach for cyclic rotation of a string

Tags: java, string

I have written a program to generate all the cyclic rotations for a particular string using recursion. Please let me know if my approach is correct. Please suggest any improvements to this code.

Example 
input string = "abcd"

Output :

abcd
bcda
cdab
dabc

```
public class CyclicRotationOfString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String s = "abcd";
        String orig =s;
        //cyclicRotate(s, orig); //approach 1
        cyclicRotate(s, s.length()); //approach 2
    }

    //approach 1    
    public static String cyclicRotate(String s, String orig) {
        String ns=null;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(s.substring(1));
        sb.append(s.charAt(0));
        ns = sb.toString(); 
        System.out.println(s);
        if(ns.equals(orig)) {
            return ns;
        }
        cyclicRotate(ns,orig);
        return ns;
    }

    //approach 2
    public static String cyclicRotate(String s, int len) {
        len--;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(s.substring(1));
        sb.append(s.charAt(0));
        String ns = sb.toString(); 
        System.out.println(s);
        if(len==0) {
            return ns;
        }
        cyclicRotate(ns,len); //break out after comparing the string
        return ns;
    }


}
```

Comment: Looking for [codereview.se]?

Comment: thank you @shmosel. Going forward I will post the question in code review.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't need to use recursion one simple approach may be like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String original = "abcd", d = original;
    do {
        System.out.print(d + " ");
    }
    while(!(d = (d.substring(1) + d.charAt(0))).equals(original));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is way cleaner and concise than the one I have written.